# Delete/hide ETH address on Ledger Nano S

Tags: blockchain, wallets, myetherwallet, etherscan, cpp-ethereum

Is it possible to delete / hide one of ETH addresses that my Ledger Nano S is providing after logging via MyEtherWallet?

I know ledger is allowing me to use lots of addresses. It is displaying the long list right after connecting and entering PIN code.

Currently I use only 2 of them for - one for trading and one for mining. However the first one got compromised and I know that someone else connected me already with that address... This means he can check my current balance and all the transactions I perform there. This is why I want to transfer the current balance from that, switch to different one and stop using the original one forever.

Is there any way I can remove the address from my list? I know it might seem stupid for some of you, but I would prevent using it even by mistake for future transactions - and have back again only two addresses with non-zero balance (including the new one for trading).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No.

The seed words associated with your ledger generate the private keys for these addresses, and (afaik) there is no way to delete/hide a specific one (you could to that in a specific application, but not in a permanent/across devices way).

You could generate/use new seed words, but that will lead to an entire new set of addresses, so you would have to transfer the existing balances to these new addresses (not just for ETH) or switch between the sets of seed words.

Comment: Please note that the question itself does not make any sense, so before answering we need to figure out what the user has actually been up to.

Comment: As far as I understand it, he just wants the first indexed address generated from the ledger to not be displayed in any of the apps he might use it on, for privacy reasons, and not because his keys got compromised in any way.

So in that way, I consider my reply an answer to "is there a way to permanently remove one of the ETH addresses that the ledger generates from this set of seed/recovery words so that it never shows up again regardless of what app I connect it to"

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for Ledger Nano addresses to get compromised unless somebody somehow managed to copy your seed words. Ledger Nano never exports private key out from the device, so it is not possible for you to leak this information yourself. Ledger Nano can generate infinite number of private keys (and addresses) from one seed work as this is a property of hierarchical deterministic wallets. If one address is "compromised" then all addresses are compromised.

Most likely you are misinterpreting something. Because the question lacks accurate facts, like why you think some address is compromised, it is impossible to tell.